# Ignore Whitespace in textfield

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, whitespace

I have a text field on my web app. In this field is a url address that user can specify.

If a user sets an incorrect url address that is prefixed with a space, `" www.blablabla.xyz"` for example, I want to ignore this and correct url will be set (`"www.blablabla.xyz"`). The * value is presenting some method.

I use `<%: Html.* %>` conditions and I hold this set URL there.

Imagine this is something like that: `<%: Html.*(doom =>doom.MyURL)%>`

MyURL is a string value. So is there any method to ignore whitespaces in this case? If yes, how can i do it?

I tried add `.Trim()` after `doom.MyURL (doom.MyURL.Trim())` but this give me an error..

ADD:
I think maybe I can edit the declaration of MyURL in .cs file?
Now MyURL is defined as:
`public string MyURL { get; set;}`

Is there any easy option to specify this "ignore" here in .cs ?

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide more details of it?

Comment: I bet `MyURL` is actually a `Uri` which you need to `.ToString()` explicitly before you can `Trim()` it.

Comment: The given error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  'System.NullReferenceException'.

Comment: I tried now: "(doom.MyURL.ToString().Trim())" but it also gives me the same error:  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 'System.NullReferenceException'.

Comment: `doom` or `MyURL` is null. Debug. Use breakpoints. Trim is what you need here for your original question, anyways.

Comment: I debug, i use breakpoints. Those show me that myURL is correct get from textfield but is still with whitespace : " www.blablabla.xyz". I tried set ToString() in different place but it gives me this error: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: paste your method here

Comment: Html.LabelFor, Html.TextBoxFor , Html.ValidationMessageFor, Html.Hidden I use this methods and holds / works on myURL inside them

Comment: Pease look at my edit question it maybe show another option now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which will help you to find white space in your string and replace it with non white space.

```
      yourString.Replace(" ","");
```

Comment: this also don't help the error as earlier. Please notice that adding .Trim() or Replace() method is running on Html.* method. I.E Html.TextBoxFor, Html.Hidden -> it is understanding by visual that you want to use Trim()/Replace() method on (in our case) Hidden/TextBoxFor. I got this from other sites where bug about "Templates can be used only with field access[...]" occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
    yourString.TrimStart(string.WhiteSpace);
```

Comment: also the same error -> look at my description below your comment about .Replace() method