# C# Ignore Whitespace in string {get; set;} declaration

Tags: c#, string, whitespace

I didn't get good answer to my earlier question [Ignore Whitespace in textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391754/ignore-whitespace-in-textfield) so I have another and I hope it will help me.

I have this declaration of string in c#:
`public string MyURL { get; set; }`

My question is: Can i specify some instruction to setter which will ignore white space when the user set this string in my web app?

Comment: If you're not getting good answers for your question, that's usually a sign that you need to **edit** your question to improve it. Not open a new one.

Answer (score 4):

```
private string _myUrl;
public string MyURL {
    get { return _myUrl; }
    set {
        // ...
        _myUrl = value.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

*edit*

guess that @Dmitry Bychenko is right. my answer doesn't cover all potentiel cases. `Regex` would be the better way to solve this!

Comment: adding to this answer, I would also consider using the `_myUrl = value.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Trim();` incase there is `"  "` with two more bits of white space because this `_myUrl = value.Replace(" ", string.Empty)` alone would only pick up single character spaces

Comment: Counter example: `"some url"` (note *non breaking space*), expected output is `"someurl"`

Comment: @SimonPrice - that original Replace will replace *all* space characters with "nothing", so no extra Trim is needed.

Comment: @SimonPrice you are wrong, because value.Replace pick each all single space and all of them are replaced by empty string :) Tested.

Comment: Another counter example is `"some\r\nurl"`: both `\n` and `\r` should be removed from the result.

Answer (score 3):

*Whitespaces* aren't just *spaces* (but also *non breaking spaces*, *zero width spaces* etc.), so I suggest using *regular expressions*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  ...
  private string m_MyURL;

  public string MyURL {
    get {
      return m_MyURL;
    }
    set {
      m_MyURL = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s", (MatchEvaluator) ((match) => ""));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace(" ", String.Empty)` to eliminate all whitespaces.

```
private string _MyURL;

public string MyURL
{
    get
    {
        return _MyURL;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyURL = value.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Counter example: `"some\r\nurl"`. Both `\n` and `\r` should be removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that there are no whitespaces left in `MyURL`?

Than this could help you:

```
    private string _MyURL;
    public string MyURL
    {
        get { return _MyURL; }
        set { _MyURL = value.Replace(" ", ""); }
    }
```

Little explanation why I added the private field:
If you wouldn't do that, you'd create an endless loop since the setter is calling the setter again.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Counter example: `"some\r\nurl"`. Both `\n` and `\r` should be removed from the result.